# how to read interrupt status (active, pending, active-pending, ..) in aarch64 gicv3?

Tags: assembly, interrupt, arm64

How can I read the interrupt status of a specific INTID in aarch64?
I want to know the state (inactive/active/pending/active-pending) of an FIQ interrupt (for example INT 208).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is "ARM® Generic Interrupt Controller, Architecture Specification" document.

It describes register structure of GIC and contains information you are looking for

> The GICD_ICACTIVERs provide a Clear-active bit for each interrupt that
> the GIC supports. Writing to a Clear-active bit Deactivates the
> corresponding interrupt. These registers are used when preserving and
> restoring GIC state.

> [31:0] Clear-active bits For each bit: 
> Reads 
> 0 The corresponding interrupt is not activea. 
> 1 The corresponding interrupt is active. <--- here
> Writes
>  0 Has no effect. 
> 1 Deactivates the corresponding interrupt, if
> the interrupt is active. If the interrupt is already deactivated, the
> write has no effect. After a write of 1 to this bit, a subsequent read
> of the bit returns the value 0.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to read the 'active' state and found there are registers for 'pending' state too.